# Create one multichannel matrix from several multichannel matrices

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to create a multichannel matrix from several other multichannel matrices. The function provided by OpenCV `cv::merge()` is to merge several single channel matrices into one. When used to merge multichannel matrices, it provides incomplete/wrong result.

My approach to this problem:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> inputMats; // vector of BGR matrices (3 channels each)
std::vector<cv::Mat> splitMats;
for (const auto& mat : matrices)
{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
    cv::split(mat, channels);
    splitMats.insert(splitMats.end(), channels.begin(), channels.end());
}
cv::Mat result;
cv::merge(splitMats, result);
```

This approach is too slow though. It takes 27 ms to merge 6 colour matrices into one 18-channel matrix (Intel Core i5 3.2GHz). Is there a different approach?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just use a vector of cv::Mat? split and merge will copy the data, if you have a vector or array of 18 cv::Mat then the data is copied once and the access is easy. BTW, what do you mean by: `When used to merge multichannel matrices, it provides uncomplete/wrong result.` what is wrong?

Comment: The input is a vector of colour matrices which are 3-channels, these cannot be directly put to the `cv:: merge()` as it merges only 1-channel matrices. Wrong/incomplete means the merge was not done correctly when applied to multichannel matrices and the resulting image was in 3/4 empty. No wonder given the method is not made for that.

Comment: Besides number of channels, do all "matrices" have the same type and depth?!

Comment: Yes, they do have the same type and depth.